# How to correct a percentage given another percentage?

Tags: probability, percentages

On the (dutch) news there was stated that judge James Robart made the following statement:

***41% of the police violence involves black people, while only 20% of the population is black***

Now the question is, if the black population was not 20% but 50%, what would the the percentage of police violence involving black people be?

Comment: It is not determined from that data (even if you make some simplifying assumptions).  You also need to know something like the percentage of the black population that experiences police violence.

Comment: Suppose police meeting black person incites violence with probability $p_{B}$ and meeting white person incites violence with probability $p_{W}$. Then the fraction of violence that involves black people is $\frac{\frac{1}{5}p_{B}}{\frac{1}{5}p_{B}+\frac{4}{5}p_{w}}=0.41$. Multiple $(p_{B},p_{W})$ satisfy this equation and will map into different fraction of violence if the fraction of black people is $50\%$